How to detect multiple tasks in a single command using LLM or any NLP model?
I am building a bot that takes inputs from users and performs action. Now I want it to differentiate between commands that contain single task and multiple tasks.
How can I make this a reality? Should I utilize prompting but there are infinite types of commands and infinite ways they can be represented, I doubt if an LLM will be able to comprehend it across all commands.
Or should I train a model or fine-tune an LLM to comprehend it but yet again the dataset would be too big and there will be infinite ways a single command can be represented.
What do you guys suggest I do?

If command=API call, look at the opensource solutions on  https://gorilla.cs.berkeley.edu/leaderboard. Mapping user prompt to an actual API call is typically either learned via finetuning (e.g., LLaVA), or via describing API functions in the LLM call (e.g., GPT's function feature).

Thanks for the reply but these commands are not about API calls but rather some flow creation like "When a message pops up on my Teams, I should receive an email."
